# Is $\lim_{x \to -∞} (2+3x)^{2/3}$ positive or negative?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$\lim_{x \to -∞} (2+3x)^{2/3}$

Is this $(-∞)^{2/3} = (-∞^2)^{1/3} = +∞$ ?

Comment: I think you may want to clarify your definition of $t^{2/3}$ for $t<0$. Usually, $t^{\alpha}$ is defined only for $t\ge0$ and, when we want to use roots, we write $\sqrt[b]{\ }$ to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: By the way: it is also the reason why answers keep popping out and being deleted.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I see no problem at all with $\;t^{2/3}\;$ for $\;t<0\;$ . I think it is very well defined, whether one takes it as $\;\left(t^2\right)^{1/3}\;$ or as $\;\left(t^{1/3}\right)^2\;$ . Even using the logarithm one can always put $\;t^{2/3}=e^{\frac23\log|t|}\;$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Are you sure? Think again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand the number of deleted answers to this question, and the number of nonsensical comments on this page.

You are essentially asking whether $x ^{\frac 2 3}$ has a meaningful definition when $x<0$. Of course it does, maybe you'll see it more clearly if you write it as $(\sqrt[3] x)^2$ or, equivalently, $\sqrt[3] {x^2}$. Both expressions involving cubic roots do make sense. In fact, $x^{\frac p q}$ makes obvious sense when $q$ is odd, no matter who the real number $x$ is.

In particular, since $(\sqrt[3] x)^2$ is a square of a real number, it is positive, so your limit is indeed $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the answers were indeed quite confusing, I actually followed up on this question, I was so confused... Please take a look: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709210/evaluating-lim-x-to-%E2%88%9E-frac-sqrt23x-ln1-x

Comment: I can't understand this: I answered  this almost 40 minutes ago, and commented **exactly** this under the question, yet my answer got downvoted and this one not only gets upvoted but also accepted. Some people behaves very weirdly in this site, and I'm sorry to say so.

Comment: @Joanpemo: ...So you downvote my question. Very mature and intelligent! *Some people behaves very weirdly in this site, and I'm sorry to say so.* For the record: I haven't downvoted anything on this page. Also for the record: downvoting as "retaliation" can bring you to the moderators' attention, so please reconsider your attitude.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you. Excuse me, *what question of yours*?? I've downvoted the new question by Eric Johnson, and I have no idea who downvoted my answer (though I suspect the asker or one of the *other* two older answerers) here and I wasn't saying, and not even hinting, that it was you! I honestly have no idea what question of yours are you talking about. I wonder whether accusing without proof can bring you to the moderators' attention...

Comment: @Joanpemo: Ok, then. Somebody downvoted my (correct) answer just a few minutes after I had posted it.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you. I'd love you  invite the moderators (if that can be done) to check that: it wasn't me. I dislike downvotes, specially unexplained ones. Besides, why would I downvote your question when it says the same I said in my answer and in my comments?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

> Does the given limit *exist* finitely at all?

Comment: I think it does: $\;x^{2/3}=\left(x^{1/3}\right)^2\;$ and this is defined for all the reals.

Comment: @Joanpemo What is the limit according to you? $+\infty$??

Comment: Thank you. Yes. It is so in my answer.

Comment: @Joanpemo In general, limits are considered to be finite. So you cannot call $+\infty$ to be strictly a limit.

Comment: Thank you. That differs from what I know. If at all, one can talk of the limit existing *finitely* or of *generalized limit*. **Not existing limit** is, in my opinion, something very different. It can be a matter of language, though.

Comment: @Joanpemo I have edited my hint. Does the language sound better now?

Comment: @SchroI Thank you. Now it does, though I understood the question itself otherwise

Comment: Does it matter if the limit is finite? It doesn't.  And no, limits are not necessarily finite. Do not confuse the expression "being convergent" (which, indeed, means "having a *finite* limit") with "having a limit" (which poses no constraint on the limit).

Answer (score -1):

$$(2+3x)^{2/3}=x^{2/3}\left(3+\frac2x\right)^{2/3}\xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{}+\infty\cdot3^{2/3}=+\infty$$