# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to -∞} \frac{\sqrt[3]{2+3x}}{\ln(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$\lim_{x \to -∞} \frac{\sqrt[3]{2+3x}}{\ln(1-x)}$$

This looks like an indetermination of the form $\frac{-∞}{∞}$, so we apply l'Hospital:

$$\frac{x-1}{(2+3x)^{2/3}}$$

However now, the denominator is undefined. How do we proceed?

I asked this question: [Is $\lim_{x \to -∞} (2+3x)^{2/3}$ positive or negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709145/is-lim-x-to-%E2%88%9E-23x2-3-positive-or-negative/1709211#1709211)

but nobody agreed in the answers.

Comment: Sigh, why the downvotes..

Comment: The expression in your title differed from the one in the text, until a few seconds ago. That is probably the reason for the downvote. Note that the downvote is not mine. It was difficult to edit the question, since it was not completely clear that that the title was the wrong expression.

Comment: I understand. Care to help nonetheless? @RoryDaulton

Comment: I think it is better to substitute $-x$ by $u\to +\infty$ and use $\sqrt[3]{-x} = -\sqrt[3]{x}$. However, I don't see that your denominator is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Previous answer deleted, due to a change in the question.)

Your denominator is not undefined.

$$(2+3x)^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{(2+3x)^2}$$

which is well-defined and non-negative for all $x$. You can continue your calculations with another round of L'Hopital:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-1}{(2+3x)^{2/3}} &\to \frac{1}{\frac 23(2+3x)^{-1/3}\cdot 3}\\[2 ex]
 &= 2(2+3x)^{1/3}
\end{align}$$

As $x\to-\infty$, we get $2+3x\to-\infty$ and $\sqrt[3]{2+3x}\to-\infty$, thus the entire expression tends to minus infinity, which is your final answer.

This is confirmed numerically. My evaluations of $f(x)$ slowly but surely become more negative, with $f(-1000000)\approx -19.2779$. Each additional zero on $x$ increases the magnitude of $f(x)$ by a factor of a little less than two.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is perfectly defined as long as $x \ne - \frac 2 3$, but this is not a problem, since $x \to -\infty$ means that $x$ goes "downwards" "past" $-\frac 2 3$ i.e it stays in some neighbourhood $(-\infty, a)$ of $-\infty$, and you are free to choose $a$ as you please, so just take it smaller than $-\frac 2 3$ and the denominator is fine.

Your approach is correct and you should continue by applying L'Hospital's rule one more time. Alternatively, if $t = -x$ (so that $t \to \infty$), write

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{2+3x}}{\ln(1-x)} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-\sqrt[3]{-2-3x}}{\ln(1-x)} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-\sqrt[3]{-2+3t}}{\ln(1+t)} = - \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1+t} {(-2 + 3t)^{\frac 2 3}}$$

and, applying L'Hospital's theorem once more,

$$-\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1+t} {(-2 + 3t)^{\frac 2 3}} = -\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac 1 {3 \frac 2 3 (-2 + 3t)^{-\frac 1 3}} = -\frac 1 2 \lim_{t \to \infty} (-2 + 3t)^{\frac 1 3} = -\infty .$$